# How to get Jasper reports 6.5.1 to populate json table

Tags: json, jasper-reports

This is similar to previous questions, but it has me stumped.  I'm using Studio 6.5.1 CE version.  So I have json data in a file that starts

```
{
    "users": {
        "itemCount": 30,
        "items": [{
            "id": 1,
            "username": "user1",
...
```

My main json query is blank, with a single field defined: itemCount with expression "users.itemCount".

I have a Details band table and "UserDataset" with jsonql query "users.items".  There are fields "id" with expression "id", "username" with expression "username", etc.  Data preview shows the fields accurately.

When running the report I do see the single itemCount field populated.  The problem is the table is missing.  Apparently I cannot successfully tie the Datasource to the table.  I have tried all sorts of expressions, and I thought something like this should work:

```
<datasetRun...>
    ...
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}).subDataSource("users.items")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

However, I can never get the table populated.  What am I doing wrong?  (I have similar report formats with jdbc sources and I have no problem with those tables.)

I can't find any combination of query/expression that works, so I am appending the jrxml file with style info stripped out for viewing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Users" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="61928541-d006-4374-9164-985c6c4116c9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Users.json"/>
    <subDataset name="UserDataset" uuid="effd13cd-71de-4771-b706-d68b1042b564">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Users.json"/>
        <queryString language="jsonql">
            <![CDATA[users.items]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="id"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="username" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="username"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[username]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="itemCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="users.itemCount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[itemCount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="116" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="-9" y="50" width="770" height="62" uuid="7d7f19b0-9800-43ab-86a4-45846dae7775">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="UserDataset" uuid="fdfe69e2-eeac-4287-9e41-4c39610a79be">
                        <datasetParameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{JSON_INPUT_STREAM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.source}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.sources">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.sources}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.date.pattern">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.date.pattern}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.number.pattern">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.number.pattern}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="JSON_LOCALE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{JSON_LOCALE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.locale.code">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.locale.code}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="JSON_TIME_ZONE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{JSON_TIME_ZONE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.timezone.id">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.timezone.id}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}).subDataSource("users.items")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="30" uuid="65fed6e9-ae42-4e04-b0b4-e2c8ef4a1b27">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" uuid="becae13f-4af9-4884-9b38-ab19347e9455"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[USER_ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" uuid="8c6b26dc-c436-4e68-acd5-89c33e09dac6"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="224b44e6-a9c2-4407-891d-623c7d6b33dc">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="3c961dd1-f991-4cde-9d22-224d4f3ae86c"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="3acbeee1-e7a4-4f45-b54c-b10c69bf7a95"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{username}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="683b48a8-3f4d-4a3a-9ab5-df8255699b8b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="39" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="326" y="6" width="100" height="30" uuid="94b2cbaa-c1f0-4934-a304-a0c4c84486a0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page" +$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Try leaving the “UserDataset” with no/empty query. Your subDatasource expression already navigates there.

Comment: Couldn't find any combination of query navigation and expression that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subDataset should have no query, like this:

```
<subDataset name="UserDataset" uuid="effd13cd-71de-4771-b706-d68b1042b564">
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="id"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="username" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="username"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[username]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

And your table's datasetRun should only use the correct expression, like this, with nothing else in it (you were casting the REPORT_CONNECTION to JsonDataSource):

```
<datasetRun subDataset="UserDataset" uuid="fdfe69e2-eeac-4287-9e41-4c39610a79be">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("users.items")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

Comment: YES!  This is the answer.

Comment: I also discovered that the real cure here is having the correct dataSource expression, with the "users.items" query.  The subDataset can have the same query in order to read and define fields from the json datasource.  This also provides the easy ability to define fields as a relative query further into the json structure, as I have a "fullName" field with expression "userProfile.fullName", where the absolute path is users.items.userProfile.fullName.

Comment: I think that the subDataset query works only because the Studio injects the adapter there. Outside Studio it should not work.

Comment: I had trouble getting the server to honor a data adapter. Finally I added this to the jrxml file:
     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="repo:/JsonResources/ds_JsonUsers"/>
where ds_JsonUsers is the adapter uploaded from Studio.

Comment: However, the REST_V2 interface call to run the report errors out with a "generic error" - and no text anywhere.  Is this related to the means in which I have defined the adapter?

Comment: If this was the answer for your original question, please mark it appropriately so that others could benefit from it. Regarding your new REST_v2 issues you could ask a new question and provide details with steps to reproduce.